# Can conversion functions be non-member functions

Tags: c++, casting, operator-overloading

Is it possible to define the casting operator from one type to another type outside of the class definition as a non-member function? I know it is possible for other operators like operator- but It is not possible with cast operators. For example for two classes A and B, I tried to define the casting operator outside of the A and B scopes as follows:

```
operator A(const B& b)
{
    A a(....);
    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, conversion functions must be member functions.

From C++11, [class.conv.fct]/1:

> A **member function** of a class `X` having no parameters with a name of the form [`operator` *conversion-type-id*] specifies a conversion from `X` to the type specified by the *conversion-type-id*. Such functions are called conversion functions.

There are no other conversion functions, in particular there are no non-member conversion functions.

Comment: but you have defined the casting operator in the struct! I mean, if you dont define 'operator int() const;' in the struct, can you write a function outside of the struct scope to cast your struct to int?

Comment: @mmostajab Like any other member function, that `operator` can be declared in the class definition and defined out-of-line, but the class implementor will have already provided that, so you can't define your own version without writing ill-formed code that exhibits multiple definition errors.

Answer (score 1):

Conversion operators are specific to class i.e they provide a means to convert your-defined type to some other type. So, they must be the member of a class for which they are serving purpose :-

for e.g:-

```
class Rational
{
  public:
     operator double ();
};
```

Here operator double provide a means to convert Rational object to double.

Comment: My problem is that I dont have access to those classes and I have to one object from one class to another. is there any way to write the caster function by myself outside of the classes scope?

Comment: That's what I said conversion functions must be members of class. i.e you can't define it as non-member function...

Comment: @Mortezamostajab It is often better to avoid implicit conversions altogether and write explicit conversion functions, anyway. Implicit conversions cause more bugs than they help avoid.