# Is it possible to implement automatic global casts?

Tags: c++

I have multiple dependencies which define exactly same data structures.

For example, `DirectX::XMFLOAT3` from Windows SDK, `std::array<float,3>` from STL, `openvdb::v6_1::math::Vec3s` from openvdb, `gte::Vector3<float>` from GTEngine, `Eigen::Vector3f` from Eigen, they have 100% compatible memory layout i.e. sizeof=12, alignof=4, holding 3 float values. I’m using all these libraries in a single project, and this ain’t a complete list, I have more.

Is there a way to implement some global conversation operators, or maybe preprocessor trickery, to allow C++ compiler to transparently cast across all these types?

I’m not willing to modify the source code of any of these libraries, too risky, and too much work.

Currently I’m making inline functions to convert across them. But as the count of libraries increases, the amount of work grows as O(N^2). Also I don’t like neither implementing nor calling these inline functions which do nothing useful, just circumvent C++ type checker, and litter my source code.

Comment: There's very little that C++ will do automatically for you. The short answer is: no, you will have to write all the conversion operators yourself.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik All 20 of them for just 5 structures? And no way to automate with macros or templates?

Comment: For 7 identical structures, the count grows to 42 :-(

Comment: @Soonts No, I don't think so.  You can write a general purpose converter like `template <typename T, typename U> T* convert(U* p) { return reinterpret_cast<T*>(p); }`, but I am afraid you can't go any further than that.

Comment: It's not much, but you can make it linear instead of quadratic by converting to some unified representation first, and then to the resulting type. Calls will be even more ugly, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you'd just write conversion operator overloads, but unfortunately they can't be global. [They must be members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26994485/can-conversion-functions-be-non-member-functions).

One way to do what you want could be to write your own type that can be converted to and from all these different types, and use that instead. For example, imagine `Type1` and `Type2` in this example are the external types (like `XMFLOAT3` or `gte::Vector3<float>`). Then you'd write your own type `MyType` that holds the same information, but can be converted to and from the other two. This is a minimal example:

```
struct Type1 {
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
};

struct Type2 {
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
};

struct MyType {
    double x_;
    double y_;
    double z_;

    MyType(double x, double y, double z)
        : x_(x), y_(y), z_(z)
    {}


    MyType(const Type1& t1)
        : x_(t1.x) , y_(t1.y) , z_(t1.z)
    { }

    MyType(const Type2& t2)
        : x_(t2.x) , y_(t2.y) , z_(t2.z)
    { }

    operator Type1() const
    {
        return Type1{x_, y_, z_};
    }

    operator Type2() const
    {
        return Type2{x_, y_, z_};
    }
};
```

You would then be able to write:

```
// External APIs
void func1(Type1);
void func2(Type2);
Type1 getT1();
Type2 getT2();

int main()
{
    MyType my_type(0, 0, 0);
    Type1 t1 = my_type;
    Type2 t2 = my_type;

    my_type = t1;
    my_type = t2;

    func1(my_type);
    func2(my_type);

    my_type = getT1();
    my_type = getT2();
}
```

You're out of luck if the APIs expect pointers though. It won't work with pointers.

Also a big caveat here: I never needed this myself and don't know if it constitutes some known anti-pattern. I hope others will chime in on whether or not this is actually a good idea or not.